# Цикл for обходит не всю коллекцию

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть таблица, которая генерируется следующим образом:

```
let table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute('border','1');

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let newRow = table.insertRow(0);
    for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        let newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
        newCell.className = "white_cell";
    }
}

document.getElementById("for_table").appendChild(table)
```

Есть кнопка, которая должна менять цвет ячеек с белого на чёрный с помощью такой функции

```
function change_color() {
    let arrCell_w = document.getElementsByClassName("white_cell");
    console.log(arrCell_w.length);
    console.log(arrCell_w);
    for (let i = 0; i < arrCell_w.length; i++) {
       //console.log(i)
       //console.log(arrCell_w[i]);       
         arrCell_w[i].className = "black_cell";
    }
}
```

Судя по логам, находятся всё, что нужно, но цвет меняется только у половины ячеек. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: как и в случае со `.splice` можно просто обходить коллекцию с конца

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` возвращает "живую" `HTMLCollection` коллекцию элементов.

На первой итерации мы получаем первый элемент по индексу `[0]` и изменяем его класс `cell.black_cell`. В этот момент коллекция `table.cell.white_cell` обновляется и первый элемент из нее выпадает. На второй итерации мы обращаемся к индексу `[1]`, но в обновленной коллекции, второй элемент таблицы сместился в индекс `[0]`. Таким образом, мы пропустили второй элемент и реально получили третий. По итогу раскрасится все через один элемент.

| index table | 1 итерация / index cell | 2 итерация / index cell |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | c_white [0] <- мы тут | c_black |
| 1 | c_white [1] | c_white [0] <- пропустили |
| 2 | c_white [2] | c_white [1] <- мы тут |

Просто превратим эту коллекцию в "неживой" массив.

```js
let table = document.createElement("table")
table.setAttribute('border', '1')

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let newRow = table.insertRow(0)
  for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    let newCell = newRow.insertCell(0)
    newCell.className = "white_cell"
    newCell.textContent = "Cell"
  }
}

document.body.appendChild(table)

function change_color() {
  let arrCell_w = [...document.getElementsByClassName("white_cell")]
  for (let i = 0; i < arrCell_w.length; i++) {
    arrCell_w[i].className = "black_cell"
  }
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", change_color)
```

```css
.white_cell {
  background-color: white;
}

.black_cell {
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<button start>Start</button>
```